# SQL Server / SSIS: Create new ID for inserted row of merge

Tags: sql-server, merge, ssis, sequence

I am kind of stuck:

Scenario:

I have a SSIS-Package, which loads data incrementally. In the first step, I load rows from a source which have a) been inserted or b) updated into a staging table. I do this by using the last timestamp of the source table.
In the next step, I am trying to use a MERGE-Statement to update the data in another database (similar to a data warehouse). I have no control over this other database, otherwise my task would be quite easy.

Problem:

The data warehouse table includes an ID-Column ([cId], BIGINT), which it does not set by itself. I have tried to create a sequence, from which I pull a value whenever I insert a new row into the data warehouse (not when I update a row, since that row will already have an ID). However, as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), SQL Server will not let me use the next value from my sequence for the target of a MERGE-Statement. Since I have no control over the data warehouse, I cannot change this.

Another solution would be to get the next value from my sequence when I load the data into the staging table. This, however, will result in "holen" in my ID-sequence, because when I update a row in the data warehouse from my staging table, the [cId] column would not be updated, since that row already has an ID.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? I am basically trying to pull a new, unique BIGINT, whenever I do an insert inside my MERGE-Statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your heart set on merge? Since you are loading into a staging table, you could split the operation into an update, followed by an `insert ... from src left join dest on ... where dest.somekey is null`, You can avoid a few reads by using some composable DML to "dequeue" the rows from your staging table (delete ... output deleted.etc) when doing the update, so that you know that all the remaining rows are inserts without having to perform another join

Comment: Hi @allmhuran, my heart is not set on using merge. I'll give this a show, thank you!

Comment: Good stuff, that works :) thanks a ton, somehow I did not consider doing the merge manually